# Need People Picker control in SharePoint designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I am unable to find a people picker control in sharepoint designer.

I am editing my NewForm.aspx that comes in a list "Add a New Item" in SP Designer 2013, 
added some text below the columns and above the save button i.e. located at bottom of the form.
I tried to search for peoplepicker control in the designer given controls but I am unable to find it. Sitting on this for a long time and couldn't find it

Help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

You can do in two way

**Option 1 Client Side**

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 

<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false"/>
```

Add the below javascript to your code on your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

          // Specify the unique ID of the DOM element where the// picker will render.
          initializePeoplePicker('peoplePickerDiv');
      });

      function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {

          var schema = {};
          schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
          schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
          schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
          schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
          schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
          schema['Width'] = '280px';
          schema['Height'] = '55px';

          this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
      }

      function getUserInfo() {

          var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;

          var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
          var userInfo = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
              var user = users[i];
              for (var userProperty in user) {
                  userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
              }
          }
         // $('#resolvedUsers').html(userInfo);

          var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
         // $('#userKeys').html(keys);
          document.getElementById('<%=RandomList.ClientID%>').value =keys ;
      }




</script>
```

Add this div in the place you want the control

```
<div id="peoplePickerDiv" style="height: 22px" >

  </div>
```

Reference:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx

**Option 2 :- Server Side**

Add this code in your .ascx page

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="spPeoplePicker" runat="server" Width="350" SelectionSet="User" />
```

You can also refer to link below. it is showing same problem you have now. there is no difference to take PeoplePicker in SP 2010 and SP 2013.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sharepoint2010programming/thread/7ce91149-e3d7-4178-8c10-4a87e7352197

http://spobject.blogspot.com/2013/02/clientpeoplepicker-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: This is the "good" people picker, right? The one which predicatively shows matching users?

Comment: Yes It is and you can see it is documented by MSDN that too Microsoft Official documentation

Comment: I can't figure out where to put the first bit of code. In designer all the code is locked down and I can't edit it. If I try and place that code in the editable regions (inside the <ZoneTemplate> tags it all blows up.

Comment: First of all hats of you for working on New Year eve. Next right click on the file make it check out then edit in advance Then you can do

Comment: Thanks. Likewise. Happy New Year to you too! We can't checkout or ghost/unghost (whichever) the forms. I got around that part of the problem by putting them on the masterpage -- just a test site for now. I do get a good people picker, but it isn't connected to the list item that I'm editing (or I assume I was creating if I were using it on a NewForm). How do I say, "This people picker is linked to the AssignedTo column in this list."?

Comment: Check out my updated answer and in option 2 check last link

Comment: Thanks. We can't deploy anything server-side or use Visual Studio. It all needs to be done client side. Do I need to write my own REST calls to retrieve/write the value? There isn't a way just to tie it into all the other columns data that are on the form?

Comment: Code I gave you don't need to deploy but it is SharePoint inbuilt control and use from SharePoint designer